# WP8 - How to records square video (480x480)

Tags: windows-phone-8, camera, aspect-ratio, video-recording, vine

i see an app Vine
http://www.windowsphone.com/vi-vn/store/app/vine/f9e6f07e-e47e-47f5-806d-55d4f79f2b60
it can record square video 480x480 or record 640x480 and convert to square video.
i'm try research, but i can't do that, did you have any ideal for this problem ?